# How to uncompress a .bin.gz file?

Tags: gzip

I have a file named like `file.bin.gz`.

I tried using `gzip -d f.bin.gz` to uncompress it, and got a `.bin` file.

Is the correct way to uncompress `.bin` files to use `gzip -d`? Also, `.bin` is a binary file, right?

Comment: `.bin` is a binary file, yes. It is generally just used to mean one of two things: either the programmer has not documented the format, or for some reason they wish to disguise it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, what you did was one of the correct ways. **To un-gzip a `.gz` file, use [`gunzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gunzip) or `gzip -d`.**

If your gzipped file is `file.bin.gz`, you can decompress it with:

```
gunzip file.bin.gz
```

This decompresses it to `file.bin`. If the operation succeeds, the original `file.bin.gz` is automatically removed. This is to say that the gzipped file is replaced with the decompressed file.

If you want to keep the original, pass the `-k`/`--keep` flag:

```
gunzip -k file.bin.gz
```

`gzip` behaves like `gunzip` when it is invoked with the `-d`/`--decompress`/`--uncompress` flag.  So this works too:

```
gzip -d file.bin.gz
```

As with `gunzip`, the default behavior of `gzip -d` is to replace its input file once it succeeds. You can pass both `-d` and `-k` if you want to keep the input file.

(All of this applies regardless of what kind of file you want to decompress; none of it is specific to the file having `.bin` in its name--that's just part of the example I've used, to better match your situation.)

*You can run `man gunzip` for more information, or `gunzip --help` for a summary of options.*

---

As for what the `.bin` in the filename is likely to mean, you have surmised correctly that a file named `.bin` is usually a binary file. However, there are several different kinds of files that are sometimes named this way and, furthermore, *the vast majority of binary files do **not** have `.bin` in their names.*

To get more information about what `file.bin` is, run [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/file.1.html) on it:

```
file file.bin
```

(This is not specific to `file.bin` having `file` in its name. In general for a file `abc` you can learn about what kind of file it appears to be by running `file abc`.)

(This is also not specific to the `.bin` part of the filename having Any Meaning At All)

Comment: binwalk is sometimes useful if file is not enough.

Comment: And please, do not run the .bin file to find out what it is ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to identify the type of file you can use the `file` program after decompressing:

```
file file.bin
```

will consult a database looking for known markers of file types (like the string '' or 'GIF89a') and output what kind of file it thinks it is. As stated before, sometimes programmers will use .bin to disguise a standard file type by just changing the extension.